# Creating a List from an Array - 3 ways Which one is better

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-7

We can create a list from array in following 3 ways (In Java 7),
1. Using `Arrays.asList()` 
2. Using `ArrayList.addAll()`
3. Using `Collections.addAll()`

```
// Using Arrays.asList()

String[] stringArray = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));

// Using ArrayList.addAll()

String[] stringArray = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(stringArray));

// Using Collections.addAll()

String[] stringArray = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(list, stringArray);
```

Which one is the best and for what situation? And are there any difference between these three?

Comment: Obviously, the first one needs less code...

Comment: First and second are the same. Third is a nice use of library code, but actually is also the same as first and secodn. If you don't need to modify you list after, I'd go for just `Arrays.asList(values)`, since it requires the least amount of work (`O(1)` to wrap the array).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Actually, 3 is a bit different as it does not create an intermediate unmodifyable list but adds the elements directly in a loop.

Comment: @tobias_k, agreed, but single array list wrapper is not much of an overhead there, it usually won't leave young objects space and get collected pretty quickly. At least this is what I was lead to believe anyway.

Comment: @tobias_k: the list returned by `Arrays.asList` is not unmodifiable, it’s just not resizable. The first variant differs from the others in that the `ArrayList` will directly create a backing array of the `stringArray` length, so it never has to increase the capacity in case `stringArray` is larger than the default capacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main differences are as follows:

`Arrays.asList()` creates a non-resizable `List`, used here only as an intermediate to access the `new ArrayList(List)` constructor. If you don't need a mutable list, using just `Arrays.asList()` is the simplest/cleanest solution.

`ArrayList.addAll()` would be the "standard" way of adding things to an existing list (possibly already containing data unlike in the example code), however...

`Collections.addAll()` is a convenience method:

> The behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of
>   `c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements))`, but this method is likely to run
>   significantly faster under most implementations.

Any "betterness" between the three is dependent entirely on your situation and
realistically speaking it's mainly a code style issue, rather than performance related.